# Can't access workstations via UNC anymore

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

Im not sure what happened. My 2003 AD server's group policy got fubared somehow. From the server, i can browse UNC path of my workstation that I removed from the policy. Something in the policy is now blocking UNC browsing, and also getting RPC server is unavailable when trying to run RSOP for the workstations...
What policies control RPC server, and which controls the network browsing issue, and/or are they related?

Comment: You didn't stop the "server" service on clients, did you?

Comment: no I verified that first.

Comment: ah...another server was fighting for GP control. issue resolved by demotion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be specific here, the 2008 GP MMC files are not backward compatible with 2003 GP MMC files